# Create Interactive presentation rather than modal presentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to create an interactive view controller presentation animation where the viewcontroller animates following the user's finger as they drag up. I'm basing my code off of this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions
Unfortunately, I just get a standard modal presentation rather than an interactive one. Any ideas why that might be the case? This is the function my panGesture calls through a delegate chain on its selector.

```
 _webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
    _webViewController.delegate = self;
    _animationController = [[AnimationController alloc] initWithPresentedViewController:_webViewController
                                                                                      presentingView:presentingView];
    _webViewController.transitioningDelegate = _animationController;

    [self handleGesture:_hostViewController
         presentingView:presentingView
presentedViewController:_webViewController];


- (void)handleGesture:(UIViewController *)presentingViewController
       presentingView:(UIView<PresentingViewType>*)presentingView
presentedViewController:(UIViewController *)presentedViewController{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = presentingView.panGesture;
    CGPoint viewTranslation = [presentingView.panGesture translationInView:presentingView];
    CGFloat progress = fabs(viewTranslation.y / 200);
    switch (panGesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            _isInteracting = YES;
            _transitionController = [UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition new];
            [presentingViewController presentViewController:presentedViewController
                                                   animated:YES
                                                 completion:nil];
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            _shouldCompleteTransition = progress > 0.5;
            [_transitionController updateInteractiveTransition:progress];
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            _isInteracting = NO;
            if (_shouldCompleteTransition) {
                [_transitionController finishInteractiveTransition];
            } else {
                [_transitionController cancelInteractiveTransition];
            }
            _transitionController = nil;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: How was the presented view controller was instantiated and where was its `transitioningDelegate` specified? Sometimes you see this behavior if one neglects to set the `transitioningDelegate` or do so too late in the process (e.g. `viewDidLoad` of the destination is too late).

Comment: I just updated my question. I set the transitioningDelegate of my presentedViewController right before I call the method to handleGesture

Comment: Then I'd be inclined to add log statements or breakpoints in the [`animationController(forPresented:presenting:source:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioningdelegate/1622037-animationcontroller) and (a) make sure it's getting called like you think and that the animation controller value being returned is what you believe it should be; and (b) do the same for `presentationController(forPresented:presenting:source:)` and `interactionControllerForDismissal(using:)`, too.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be called correctly. It seems that the problem is with the animation as the viewController is not animating at all as we get to the case for `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`. Any ideas on what I could do?

Comment: Hmm. So you're definitely hitting `animateTransition` in your animation controller, and the interaction controller has successfully been instantiated, too, and it's not working? I guess we need a [reproducible example of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code above is not sufficient to manifest the problem, methinks.